# Why am I not able to view all the Headers of the mail on Exchange Server using JavaMail API?

Tags: email, jakarta-mail, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm using JavaMail to read the mails in the mailbox on an Exchange Server. I used the concept of "Exchange Bridge" to access the mailbox. Using this concept, I'm able to get the count of the messages in the mailbox.
How ever, I'm not able to get the size of those mails(using `getSize()`). It always gives me 0 as the size.

Also, I used `getAllHeaders()` and iterated through the returned enum to get the name and values of the headers. But I was able to get only the following headers - `Date, From, Subject`

Why am I not able to see `Message-ID, ReferenceID, In-Reply-To` and other headers?

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you mean by "Exchange Bridge"?  Is this a separate server that sits between your JavaMail client and your Exchange server, perhaps translating IMAP or POP3 requests into MAPI requests?  If so, it's probably not doing a perfect job of translating, thus these gaps.

Comment: Bill, I'm using this JavaMail EWS plugin `ewsjava-api-1.2.6.jar`
This is what I meant by Exchange Bridge. This is to use javamail with an Exchange server using Exchange Web Services

Comment: My guess above is probably correct, that the bridge isn't doing a perfect job of translating the Exchange web services protocol to the JavaMail API, but you might want to check out the source code for the EWS plugin and check for yourself.